# What are the flow based formulations?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, modeling, combinatorial-optimization, scheduling

What are the flow-based formulations? For what optimization problems are they applied, and in which form? Which are the specificities of such a formulation?

Also, the same question for the time staged formulation.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context here? Flow-based formulations for *what*? You added the [tag:scheduling] tag, so are you asking specifically about scheduling problems? If so, it would help to include that in your title and/or question.

Comment: Yes it is about scheduling problems and tsp problems also

Answer (score 4):

**What are flow based formulations ?**

Flow based formulations can be used when working with networks. The classical approach is to define a variable for each edge of the network. In a flow based formulation, you basically perform a change of variables, and define a variable for each possible path/flow of the network.

**For what optimization problems are they applied ?**

For example, if you are solving a [multi-commodity flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-commodity_flow_problem), you would normally have a variable $x_{ij}^p$ for each edge $(i,j)$ of the network, for each commodity $p$. In a flow based formulation, you will define variables for each possible path, for example, for a path from the source to the sink, for a given commodity, you can define variable $\lambda_q, q \in \Omega$ . If you have a capacity constraint on an edge $(i,j)$, in the first model you would write $\sum_{p\in P}x_{ij}^p\le Q$. With a flow based formulation, you would write $\sum_{q\in \Omega, (i,j) \in q}\lambda_q \le Q$.

**Which are the specificities of such formulations ?**

- They have a tighter linear relaxations than edge based models
- They are designed to be used with decomposition approaches (column generation/Lagrangian relaxation)

Comment: SO, i cannot consider the traditional form you cite as a flow based formulation. the condition should be a path or a flow between them?

Comment: what is the edge flow models ? and what are the other commun flow formulations?

Comment: edge based: one variable per edge, flow based : one variable per flow/path. To my knowledge there are no other common formulations, but don't quote me on that.